# MongoDB atlas archive after total document reaches a certain number

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongodb-atlas

I want to write a custom archive rule in mongodb that archives the data with some condition.

Let's say I have a collection A.

If the collection has more than 1000 docs, archive the oldest doc (I have createdAt) until total document count is 1000. So basically, It should not exceed 1000.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement this in a number of different ways, there is no OOTB solution for this.

I would personally use a [capped collection](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/capped-collections/) with a size set to a 1000, this will let Mongo handle the most difficult part of your requirements, Regarding the "archiving" I would create an additional collection for archiving purposes and insert the document into both collections.

This will allow you to have a lean capped collection for your queries, and an additional "archive" collection for historical queries.

There are additional points to consider that you didn't specify, are the capped collection limitations an issue? do we need to support updates? what is the frequency of such operations, and so on.

Comment: Thank you Tom. This is a good way of doing what I was thinking. However, can I not do the same similarly through a custom archieve rule?

Comment: You could yes, I would personally want to simplify the system as much as I can to make sure nothing breaks, using built in capabilities achieves this.